# Why is it advised to avoid foods that are grown under the land on Shraddham days?

Tags: food, shraddha, explanation

I've learnt that certain vegetables are avoided (Onion, Garlic, beetroot etc) on Shraddham/Tharpanam days for 2 reasons:

1. They are Aphrodisiac in nature.
2. They are grown under the land.

Can someone explain, what is the story or what is the significance of the second point?

Or like, why should we avoid foods that are grown under the land? Any specific spiritual reason, or Pauranic story?

Please let me know.

Comment: They are tamasic

Comment: So, all foods grown under the land are Tamasic?

Comment: Most of them are, but potato isn't

Comment: Oh, how is it actually classified or differentiated? Could you please write an answer explaining in detail?

Comment: Potatoes are not Indian food. They were brought here by the Portugese; no way it would be explicitly mentioned in our puranas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These foods you list are to be avoided **always**, not just on special days. See Vedanta Desika's [Ahara Niyamam](https://www.srivaishnavam.com/desikaprabandam/ahara_meaning.htm) for details on what is to be avoided.

It is because those days are important, that people choose to avoid them **at least** on such important days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @hashable. But could you tell me why it should be avoided? Is it because they trigger certain feelings? Or is it because they are aphrodisiac?

Comment: In general foods that are to be avoided are foods that cultivate Tamasic Guna which is a hindrance in the pursuit to Moksha.

Comment: But why do I see references in the shastras about yogis and other people "subsisting on roots". Roots grow underground.

Comment: Who said anything about roots?